# Contracting the metric tensor with itself using Einstein summation

Tags: geometry

Say we have a diagonal metric with components $g_{\mu \nu}$. When contracting with the inverse metric, we have the identity
$$ g_{\mu \nu}g^{\nu \lambda} = \delta_{\mu}^{\lambda}.$$
When both pairs of components are equal, in the Einstein summation convention contraction should leave us with the trace of the Kronecker delta,
$$ g_{\mu \nu}g^{\nu \mu} = \delta_{\mu}^{\mu} = n$$
on an $n$-dimensional manifold.

Now let us say we have contracted a rank-2 tensor to form a scalar by
$$ g^{\nu \lambda}T_{\lambda\nu} = t.$$
If we multiply by the metric following the first equation above, we find
\begin{align}
g_{\mu\nu}g^{\nu \lambda}T_{\lambda\nu} &= g_{\mu\nu}t, \\
\Rightarrow \delta_{\mu}^{\lambda}T_{\lambda\nu}&= T_{\mu\nu} = g_{\mu\nu}t.
\end{align}
If however we multiply by the metric using the same indices, as in the second case above, we find
\begin{align}
g_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu}T_{\mu\nu} &= g_{\mu\nu}t, \\
\Rightarrow \delta_{\mu}^{\mu}T_{\mu\nu}&= g_{\mu\nu}t.
\end{align}
It seems clear that one can contract the Kronecker delta upper $\mu$ index with the lower $\mu$ index in $T_{\mu\nu}$ to obtain the same result as the first time. What is unclear to me is exactly why the interpretation $\delta_{\mu}^{\mu}=n $ in this case is incorrect. I can't seem to justify with proper rigour why that contraction makes no sense here, even though I can see that it's wrong and am otherwise happy with the correct interpretation.

My intuition is that the LHS has to be treated like a rank 4 tensor, and the trace of this tensor over the delta indices does not mean we introduce a scalar factor to the resulting contracted tensor. But this isn't a very thorough description.

Does anyone have any pointers? I'm positive I'm overlooking something very simple but quite important here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you right (I'm not 100% sure about that) the confusion is from the fact that you use the same indices three times:
$
\begin{align}
g_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu}T_{\mu\nu} &= g_{\mu\nu}t, \\
\Rightarrow \delta_{\mu}^{\mu}T_{\mu\nu}&= g_{\mu\nu}t.
\end{align}
$
Uses $\mu\nu$ three times (one up each and two down).
It should be either:
$
g_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu}T_{\lambda\delta}  = nT_{\lambda\delta} 
$
or : 
$
g_{\lambda\delta}g^{\mu\nu}T_{\mu\nu}  = g_{\lambda\delta}t
$
or maybe something like : 
$
g_{\nu\delta}g^{\mu\nu}T_{\mu\lambda}  = T_{\delta\lambda}
$
So when each greek letter is used as an index no more than two times (once up and once down) there is no confusion as to what should be summed over what and there is no contradiction in the outcome.

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot for the help.